# Manually Assigning C-states to CPUs for Energy Optimization

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu, power-management, cpu-architecture, multiprocessor

Is it possible to manually set specific C-states for CPUs, similar to how we select processor frequencies, for energy optimization purposes? I'm interested in tools or methods that allow such granular control. Any guidance or references to relevant resources would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think so. You can control boost and max frequencies though.